# Access error publishing InfoPath form to Forms Services

Tags: 2010, infopath, permissions, forms-services

I am trying to publish an InfoPath form to a SharePoint form library, but I am running into problems. Immediately after clicking the Next button in the Publishing Wizard, I receive "You are not authorized to perform the current operation" error. I am a site collection admin on the site.

Tracing the operation in Fiddler, I am getting a 403 error accessing /_vit_bin/shtml.dll/_vti_rpc. The full trace is below.

Query:

```
POST https://testsite/_vti_bin/shtml.dll/_vti_rpc HTTP/1.1
Date: Wed, 11 Jul 2012 21:09:50 GMT
MIME-Version: 1.0
User-Agent: MSFrontPage/14.0
Host: cbs.gsk.com
Accept: auth/sicily
Content-Length: 42
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Vermeer-Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

method=server+version%3a14%2e0%2e0%2e6009
```

Reply:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid: d905e7ac-6ae4-4c7d-a5c9-51533f768db8
X-SharePointHealthScore: 2
X-Forms_Based_Auth_Required: https://testsite/_login/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=/_layouts/Error.aspx&Source=%2f_vti_bin%2fshtml.dll%2f_vti_rpc
X-Forms_Based_Auth_Return_Url: https://testsite/_layouts/Error.aspx
X-MSDAVEXT_Error: 917656; Access denied. Before opening files in this location, you must first browse to the web site and select the option to login automatically.
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.6106
Date: Wed, 11 Jul 2012 21:09:50 GMT
Content-Length: 13

403 FORBIDDEN
```

How do I fix this problem? Is there some setting in SharePoint or IIS I need to tweak or enable?

Comment: Please clarify are you trying to a create a custom list through Infopath ?

Comment: No, actually it is simpler than that. I just want to publish a form to a doc lib. The error coming back is a SharePoint access-denied error. Looking for insights as to what might be going wrong.

Comment: From curiosity, why are you trying to publish Infopath form into document library but onto from library?

Comment: @WebMAOhist Thanks, you're right, it is a form library. I will correct the text above.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with "You are not authorized to perform the current operation" when publishing to a HTTPS destination.  The form template was set to Full Trust (Central Admin Administrator Approved).  However InfoPath wants to "see" that URL and confirm it's a valid destination.

I opened the HTTPS website in IE.  By clicking "View Certificate" then "Install Certificate" I was able to FIX the issue by adding to my local Trusted Root Certification Authorities.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

> "I am a site collection admin on the site"

IMO, This is irrelevant for publishing Infopath form library. If the form (for example, client/Filler)  requires a "Full trust" then the security level warning is issued and specified on the client Infopath Designer 2010 which does not know anything about server accesses and then activated on Sharepoint Server 2010 by farm administrator.
And that activation requires farm administrator privileges but not site collection administrator's one.

Also, why are you publishing and Infopath form onto document library but not to a form library?
Is it:

- in Sharepoint\Infopath 2010 ? 2007? 2003?
- in Office 365 (Sharepoint 2010 Online) ?
- browser or client/Filler form?
- etc.

Can you provide step-by-step indtructions in order to reproduce your error?

Update:
I've just checked in Fiddler2 what is requested and gotten back on pressing Next in publishing wizard to my Sharepoint Online (Office 365) site:

Request1:

```
CONNECT gennadyxxxxx.sharepoint.com:443 HTTP/1.0    
User-Agent: Microsoft Office Protocol Discovery   
Host: gennadyxxxxx.sharepoint.com:443   
Content-Length: 0   
Connection: Keep-Alive   
Pragma: no-cache   

A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.  

Major Version: 3  
Minor Version: 1  
Random: 50 04 41 2D 7A 88 5B 8F A7 0E 0D C0 50 37 6A 31 AE 0E D2 49 89 33 E2 ED 9D 25 81 8F   F8 F7 22 B7  
SessionID: 8D F5 C4 48 37 95 B6 3E 4B AF 97 4F 99 75 0C 84 73 14 F8 1F D1 65 0D 56 F0 A1 CA 43 5F 34 AA 50  
Ciphers:   

[0004]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5  
[0005]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA  
[000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
[0009]  SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_SHA  
[0064]  TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_RC4_56_SHA  
[0062]  TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_DES_SHA  
[0003]  SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5  
[0006]  SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_40_MD5  
[0013]  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA  
[0012]  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_SHA  
[0063]  TLS_DHE_DSS_EXPORT1024_WITH_DES_SHA  

Compression:   
[00]    NO_COMPRESSION  

Extensions: 
none
```

Response1:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK    
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established    
FiddlerGateway: Direct    
StartTime: 00:03:52.984    
Connection: close    

Encrypted HTTPS traffic flows through this CONNECT tunnel. HTTPS Decryption is enabled in Fiddler, so decrypted sessions running in this tunnel will be shown in the Web Sessions list.
```

Request2:

```
OPTIONS https://gennadyxxxxx.sharepoint.com/ HTTP/1.1    
User-Agent: Microsoft Office Protocol Discovery    
Host: gennadyxxxxx.sharepoint.com    
Content-Length: 0    
Connection: Keep-Alive    
Cookie: FedAuth=77u/PD....truncated_too_lengthy
```

Response2:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK    
Cache-Control: private,max-age=0    
Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD, MKCOL, PUT, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, DELETE, MOVE, COPY, GETLIB, LOCK, UNLOCK    
Content-Length: 0    
Expires: Sun, 01 Jul 2012 17:04:40 GMT    
Accept-Ranges: none    
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5    
SPRequestGuid: 02e216bc-5930-4da6-93f8-cfd19858e9c2    
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0    
MS-Author-Via: MS-FP/4.0,DAV    
X-MSDAVEXT: 1    
DocumentManagementServer: Properties Schema;Source Control;Version History;    
X-MSFSSHTTP: 1.0    
DAV: 1,2    
Public-Extension: http://schemas.microsoft.com/repl-2    
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET    
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.6109    
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"v
Date: Mon, 16 Jul 2012 17:04:40 GMT
```

Request3:

```
POST https://gennadyxxxxx.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/webs.asmx HTTP/1.1    
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8    
SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/WebUrlFromPageUrl    
X-Office-Version: 14.0.4760    
User-Agent: Microsoft Office/14.0 (Windows NT 5.1; InfoPath Editor 14.0.4760; Pro)    
Host: gennadyxxxxx.sharepoint.com    
Content-Length: 325    
Connection: Keep-Alive    
Cache-Control: no-cache    
Cookie:         FedAuth=77u/PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0........    

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">    
        <soap:Body>    
            <WebUrlFromPageUrl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">    
            <pageUrl>https://gennadyxxxxx.sharepoint.com/msdn_SBS_FormLib_Publish</pageUrl>  
        </WebUrlFromPageUrl>    
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response3:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK    
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0    
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8    
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5    
SPRequestGuid: b2067545-c868-4539-a7d4-11a9468ee01a    
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0    
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727    
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET    
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.6109    
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM     INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"    
Date: Mon, 16 Jul 2012 17:04:40 GMT    
Content-Length: 441        

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap:Body>    
            <WebUrlFromPageUrlResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">       
               <WebUrlFromPageUrlResult>
                    https://gennadyxxxxx.sharepoint.com
            </WebUrlFromPageUrlResult>
    </WebUrlFromPageUrlResponse>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Request4:
    OPTIONS https://gennadyxxxxx.sharepoint.com/ HTTP/1.1
    User-Agent: Microsoft Office Protocol Discovery
    Host: gennadyxxxxx.sharepoint.com
    Content-Length: 0
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Cookie:
     FedAuth=77u/PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiP.........

Response4:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK    
Cache-Control: private,max-age=0    
Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD, MKCOL, PUT, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, DELETE, MOVE, COPY, GETLIB, LOCK, UNLOCK    
Content-Length: 0    
Expires: Sun, 01 Jul 2012 17:04:40 GMT    
Accept-Ranges: none    
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5    
SPRequestGuid: b7f36372-91cc-4408-bd73-ac19b4ce51c9    
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0    
MS-Author-Via: MS-FP/4.0,DAV    
X-MSDAVEXT: 1    
DocumentManagementServer: Properties Schema;Source Control;Version History;    
X-MSFSSHTTP: 1.0    
DAV: 1,2    
Public-Extension: http://schemas.microsoft.com/repl-2    
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET    
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.6109    
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"    
Date: Mon, 16 Jul 2012 17:04:40 GMT
```

etc.

The first dialog window of Infopath Designer 2010 Publishing Wizard before clicking **Next** button for the 1st time:

[image: 1st dialog of Publishing Wizard from Infopath Designer 2010]

**Update 3:**
Going to sleep.

I am on Sharepoint Online (Office 365) site, OOTB. Before that I used on-premise Sharepoint Server 2010 mounted in virtual machine, taken again somewhere from MS on internet, OOTB.    Never used claims. AFAIU, NTLM or claims is irrelevant since Infopath uses its own Microsoft Office Protocol and at application level the browser based IP forms communicate with server over XMLHTTP (which is related with necessity to resolve the double hop authentication issues) while client/Filler forms via NTLM (that do not have the double hop issues).

Check that **WebDAV** is enabled on your server.

IMO Infopath uses **Microsoft Office Protocol Discovery** so check for compatibility of your server configuration with it.

Comment: SharePoint 2010 and InfoPath 2010. Create any form (even a blank form) and try to publish it. I receive this error on the first step of the wizard. This is to an on-premises farm. I have been mainly testing browser-based forms, but it is before that step the error occurs. I am mainly concerned as to why I am getting a access denied on the virtual directory.

Comment: virtual directory? Virtual directories are not created while using Sharepoint Server. Even more you should configure IIS serving non-sharepoint site and sharepoint webapps served thru distinctive ports. BTW, I've been doing it thousands times in on-premises Sharepoint Server 2010 and now onto Sharepoint Online (Office 365). BTW, from Windows XP SP3 32-bit

Comment: Ok, any thoughts why I would get a 403 accessing this path: https://testsite/_vti_bin/shtml.dll/_vti_rpc

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to publish onto non-sharepoint IIS site (virtual directory). I do not now have any at hand to check it. Are you publishing from the same machine where Sharepoint Server runs or remotely?

Comment: Also, before 1st NEXT clicking in Publishing Wizard you should not specify yet library locatuon but simply your sharepoint site _http://somthing_like_SharepointTestMachine/

Comment: Updated my answer by screenshot

Comment: How did you come to such an idea of publishing to  _http://testsite/_vti_bin/shtml.dll/_vti_rpc ? I encounter this for the very 1st time in my life

Comment: No, I am not publishing to that directory. The InfoPath publish wizard is calling into that directory. I deduced this by looking at the traffic in Fiddler. The sent query and received response are posted above. This is all generated by the OOB components. The only action I have taken is to put in the URL of my site and click next. The call to _vti_bin is generated by the wizard. Hope this clears up the sequence of events.

Comment: Your screenshots look correct. Is your site NTLM or claims (mine is claims)?

Comment: Cf. Update 3 in my answer